# Assign image to Image.Source

Tags: wpf

How to assign a picture Image.Source: Image.Source = "Images \ 1.bmp" - does not work (you can not assign a picture)

Answer (score 1):

```
Image myImage3 = new Image();
BitmapImage bi3 = new BitmapImage();
bi3.BeginInit();
bi3.UriSource = new Uri("smiley_stackpanel.PNG", UriKind.Relative);
bi3.EndInit();
myImage3.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
myImage3.Source = bi3;
```

[As mentioned above easily found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)

Don't forget to set the Build Action for '1.bmp' to Resource

Answer (score 0):

The Image.Source page at MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source.aspx has an example. You need to assign an ImageSource, not a string. (but of course see Pack URIs in above post)